# NgRX Angular outdated slice values for Effects API calls

Tags: angular, api, ngrx

I'm currently using NgRx to manage State of an Angular application.

I have the main AppState and several lazy-loaded modules with feature state management. All modules are communicating between them.

When I update an slice of the feature module store with any Effect call to an API, I update that successfully, but when another module needs to access to that slice, the state may have outdated values. How could know if the Store slice needs to be updated with a new API values, in order to avoid the related module take outdated values?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Any subscribers will receive the new value(s) as soon as they're emitted. Even if you're using `withLatestFrom` in an Effect in a different module, it will have the latest data.

Comment: Yes Brandon, but, if the backend have updated values ie. Events. that has not been populated in the Store (because a new call in the Effect was not executed) but you request the Store Event slice values through other module, the latest (including withLatestFrom) value of the Store is outdated. You need to update the Store previous.

Comment: If you don't have the latest data from your API, that's not the fault of the store. It's not NGRX's responsibility to check to see if it has the latest data. How would it even know such a thing? It's your responsibility to keep the store up to date.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't evalute the NGRX responsibility. I was asking any pattern you are using when you work with NgRx. Currently I'm evaluating the update frecuency for the data and if it needs to be updated I execute again the action that update the store slice via Effects, if the data doesn't need to be updated, then I get the current Store slice.

Comment: You have a few choices... execute a service call on an interval, when a certain route is fired, so the data is loading by the time you get to your component(s) or use sockets.

Comment: Yes,I will be evaluating the use of WebSockets if the backend implement that feature, but use routing could be a great way to get the latest data for frequently updated values right now.

Comment: See: https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/install and https://medium.com/simars/ngrx-router-store-reduce-select-route-params-6baff607dd9 for help with the NGRX Router Store